# Styling select menu from inheriting input fields?

Tags: forms, select, css, styles

Is there a way to inherit the styling of a `<select></select>` from the input fields within the same `<form>` tag? Such as width, height, border color, etc?

Comment: Just include `select` in the selector?

Comment: No, not really. You'll have to do that via CSS modification. Mind posting your CSS, if that's the case?

Comment: I see, I guess I'll just mark this answer correct, if I cant use some way like the inherit tag. Thanks for responding tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured that I can't do it except adding select in the selector

Thanks guys!